# Can't log in to Windows Server 2003 due to domain controller being unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

I'm in quite a pickle. I'm trying to log in to one of our Windows Server 2003 servers but I keep getting the error message:

`Windows cannot connect to the domain, either because the domain controller is down or otherwise unavailable, or because your computer account was not found. Please try again later. If this message continues to appear, contact your system administrator for assistance.`

This server hosts our production SQL server. The domain controller is running and my account has not been disabled or deleted. The server is hosted in a nearby data center so I can travel if need be.

Any advise on what I should do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just a member server you should be able to click the drop down on the login screen and change it to "Login to "This Computer". As long as you've got the local administrator or another account account enabled and set with a password you should be able to login.

Comment: I was able to log in locally. Now what can I do?

Comment: I would start with checking DNS and making sure it is correctly configured to point to the DC's as the DNS servers. Beyond that, you can check the event logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Like Rex said, check the DNS first. Try to ping between the servers and see what responses you get. Try to ping both the IP address and the names of the servers. Post the results here.

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek I was able to ping both the IP address and names of the domain controllers.

Comment: I'd try leaving and rejoining the domain. You'll want to do this during off hours as it will require a restart which will take your SQL database offline.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to reset the computer account to resolve the issue. You can do this by dis-joining and re-joining the server to the domain or through AD Users & Computers -> find the computer account -> right-click -> Choose reset.

Comment: Will this result in having to restart the computer that was reset?

Comment: Re-joining will for sure. Not sure about the account reset though